# Unable to nest min() and max() functions in Vite with PostCSS + TailwindCSS

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite, postcss

I'm working on a project using Vue 3, Vite, and Nuxt + TailwindCSS and I'm experiencing an issue with nesting min() and max() functions in CSS using PostCSS. The code snippet I'm working with is as follows:

```
padding-right: calc(
  min(
    max((100vw - theme('screens.desktop') + 40px) / 2, 80px),
    var(--max-padding)
  )
);
```

During the build process with Vite and PostCSS, I receive the following warning:

WARN  [vite:css] Lexical error on line 2: Unrecognized text.

The warning message highlights the specific area of concern:

```
min(
  max((100vw - 1360px + 40px) / 2, 80px),
  var(--max-padding)
)
```

Despite checking for syntax errors, verifying variable definitions, and confirming the compatibility of the functions and variables used, I'm still unable to resolve the warning. This warning only appears during the build process; in development mode, everything seems to work fine.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, workarounds, or suggestions for resolving this problem and successfully nesting min() and max() functions with Vite and PostCSS.

Despite checking for syntax errors, verifying variable definitions, and confirming the compatibility of the functions and variables used, I'm still unable to resolve the warning. This warning only appears during the build process; in development mode, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Do you have cssnano running on production build? It could be [this bug](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-calc/issues/104).